# Impersonation Step and the modified by on a created item

Tags: impersonation

I am using the default content approval process on a list in sharepoint foundation however I want it to only apply to editing existing items. 
So basically when a new item is created in the list I do not want a pending status set to and have it approved before it is displayed. To get around this I have created a workflow with an impersonation step that sets any created items to automatically approve newly created items. 
However when I look at the "modified by" column I notice that it says administrator (i.e the author of the impersonation step).
Is there anyway I can get that back to the current author of the list item?